# MLE Interpretation

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

[image]

To show this, I solved for the MLE, but as a verbal explanation, I was wondering if the following would suffice.
Since the MLE of $\theta$ is $\bar x$, given the range of the distribution $(0 < x < 2)$, the MLE is $\min(\bar X,2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, kinda. MLE is a maximization problem. I.e.

$$ \hat{\theta} = {\arg\max}_{\theta\in(0,\infty)} L(\theta) = \overline{X}.$$

You want to use this to conclude that
$$ \hat{\theta}' = {\arg\max}_{\theta\in(0,2]} L(\theta) = \min(\overline{X},2).$$

This conclusion is not valid for arbitrary functions $L$. For example

- The conclusion is not true if $L$ has a local maximum somewhere in $(0,2)$, and its global maximum in $(2,\infty)$.
- The conclusion is true however if $L$ only has a single local maximum (which is therefore the global maximum). I'm pretty sure this is true for the Poisson-Likelihood (as well as most other commonly used distrubtion functions). But it does not need to be true for general MLE.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still unsure as to how you transformed it so that min() is the mle of theta

Comment: If a function only has a single maximum on the whole domain $(0,\infty)$, and then you restrict the domain to $(0,2]$, then EITHER: The maximum was inside $(0,2]$ anyway, so nothing thanges, OR: the maximum was to the right of $2$, then the maximum of the restricted function is at $2$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that now, but how does knowing that the mle is inside (0,2] conclude that the mle is min(xbar, 2)

Comment: well the definition of $\min(a,2)$ is: if $a<2$, then $a$, otherwise $2$.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and explanations. I believe I understand it better now